# How to create Oracle user defined type in python cx_Oracle?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

`Python 3.4.3`, `cx_Oracle 5.2 11g`, `Oracle DB 11.2.0.1`

Hello!
I want to get the status of datapump job from python through `cx_Oracle`.

To solve this problem I call Oracle `dbms_datapump.get_status procedure`:

```
DBMS_DATAPUMP.GET_STATUS( 
    handle IN NUMBER, 
    mask IN BINARY_INTEGER, 
    timeout IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL, 
    job_state OUT VARCHAR2, 
    status OUT ku$_Status1120);
```

from python `cx_Oracle`:

```
get_status_params = {'handle': job_handler,
                     'mask': 1,
                     'timeout': -1,
                     'job_state': job_state,
                     'status': ??????
                     }
cursor.callproc('dbms_datapump.get_status', keywordParameters=get_status_params)
```

Structure `ku$_Status1120` in Oracle:

```
CREATE TYPE sys.ku$_Status1120 IS OBJECT
(
    mask NUMBER, 
    wip ku$_LogEntry1010, 
    job_description ku$_JobDesc1020, 
    job_status ku$_JobStatus1120,
    error ku$_LogEntry1010 
)
```

`job_status` type in oracle for example:

```
CREATE TYPE sys.ku$_JobStatus1120 IS OBJECT
        (
            job_name        VARCHAR2(30),           
            operation       VARCHAR2(30),           
            job_mode        VARCHAR2(30),           
            bytes_processed NUMBER,                 
            total_bytes     NUMBER,                 
            percent_done    NUMBER,                 
            degree          NUMBER,                 
            error_count     NUMBER,                 
            state           VARCHAR2(30),           
            phase           NUMBER,                 
            restart_count   NUMBER,                 
            worker_status_list ku$_WorkerStatusList1120,                                                        
            files           ku$_DumpFileSet1010    
    )
```

How I can repeat Oracle type `sys.ku$_Status1120` in Python?

Answer (score 2):

I have a short write up on using cx_Oracle for CRUD functionality, and in the [insert segment](http://learncodeshare.net/2015/06/26/insert-crud-using-cx_oracle/) I use the following to retrieve the value of the returning clause.

```
new_id = cur.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)

statement = 'insert into cx_people(name, age, notes) values (:1, :2, :3) returning id into :4'
cur.execute(statement, ('Sandy', 31, 'I like horses', new_id))

sandy_id = new_id.getvalue()
```

I have used this same method with out parameters from procudures both for single values `cur.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)` and arrays `cur.arrayvar(cx_Oracle.NUMBER,1000)`;

I haven't specifically used the `cx_Oracle.OBJECT` type, but I assume it works similar to other types.

Docs: [cx_Oracle.OBJECT](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/module.html?highlight=cx_oracle.number#cx_Oracle.OBJECT) and [Variable.getvalue](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/variable.html#Variable.getvalue)

Try this

```
job_status_out = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.OBJECT)

get_status_params = {'handle': job_handler,
                     'mask': 1,
                     'timeout': -1,
                     'job_state': job_state,
                     'status': job_status_out
                     }
cursor.callproc('dbms_datapump.get_status', keywordParameters=get_status_params)

job_status = job_status_out.getvalue()
```

Worst case, if you have problems with getting the value from the cur.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER) variable; you could wrap `dbms_datapump.get_status` in a pl/sql function that returns the value as a string and call that instead.  I know that works.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use cursor.var(cx_Oracle.OBJECT) previously. Result: job_status_out = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.OBJECT)
TypeError: expecting type name for object variables. I will leave a comment, when I try other solutions.

Comment: Support for binding objects has been added in the development version of cx_Oracle.  Yes, you do need to add typename=<name> to the cursor.var() statement noted above.

Comment: today i try job_status = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.OBJECT, typename='ku$_Status1010'). cursor.callproc('dbms_datapump.get_status', keywordParameters=get_status_params)
cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Variable_TypeByValue(): unhandled data type cx_Oracle.OBJECTVAR

Answer (score 1):

*This answer an alternate to the other answer I gave.  The other answer is a better solution assuming there aren't any issues with the return type.*

*This solution will work with any language that can make an SQL call to the database.  So you can still get what you need, even if the application language you're using doesn't support calling PL/SQL functions.*

If you are unable to get something from an Oracle database such as a custom type or complex data set, you can write a [pipelined table function](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2015/04/table-functions-introduction-and.html).

A pipelined table function allows you to preform whatever actions you need on the pl/sql side and format/return the results in a tabular format of your choice.

Then on the application layer, you can select from this function as if it were a table.

I have [a post here](http://learncodeshare.net/2015/11/11/node-oracledb-bind_out-to-an-array/) explaining how to use this in a NodeJS call, but I've modified this example to use Python.

In PL/SQL:

*(this doesn't have to be in a package, it's just the example I use)*

```
/* defined in package spec */
TYPE SearchType IS RECORD (
 member_id NUMBER,
 dino_name VARCHAR2(400) );

 TYPE SearchTypeSet IS TABLE OF SearchType;


/* defined in package body */
FUNCTION text_only(
  member_id_p IN INTEGER,
  search_string IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN SearchTypeSet PIPELINED
IS
 retSet SearchType;
BEGIN
  FOR v_rec IN (
     SELECT member_id,
            dino_name
       FROM dd_members
      WHERE contains (about_yourself, 
                         search_string) > 0
        AND member_id != member_id_p) LOOP
            retSet.dino_name := v_rec.dino_name;
     retSet.member_id := v_rec.member_id;
     pipe ROW (retSet);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
```

After that it's a simple select statment from the application.

In Python:

```
cur = con.cursor()
statement = 'SELECT member_id, dino_name FROM TABLE(text_only(:memberId, :keywords)) ORDER BY dino_name'
cur.execute(statement, (35, 'Rocks'))
res = cur.fetchall()
print (res)
```

For your specific issue, you could wrap the call to `dbms_datapump.get_status` in a pipelined function instead of using the select in the example.